# Is there a way to import data from another table if a statement is true? (excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

My table looks
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ2Zq.png)

I made a database file that looks.
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSBlm.png)

What I want to do is to show the "selling price" from the database in the excel cell "unit price"
when the id in the excel cell matches the id of the database file.
I searched as much as I could but ended up with nothing.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What did you use to create your database? Is it MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your database file can be imported into your spreadsheet as an external datasource (look at the options on the Data ribbon). Most sources are compatible and it will probably import all the data or part of it into a new worksheet. File size might grow a bit as you are basically duplicating the data into the spreadsheet.

Now you can easily use a VLOOKUP function to look up the id and return the price. From spreadsheet to spreadsheet.

The data will not be live but you can set an auto refresh interval, have the spreadsheet update when you open the file or press ctrl+alt+F5 to manually update from the database.

Alternatively you could venture in VBA coding and code direct live database access. If you really needed to.